# How do I click this button using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<input class="ch4_btn ch4_btnOrange ch4_btnDropShadow ch4_btnPlaceOrder" value="PLACE ORDER" type="button">
```

How do I "click" this button using selenium webdriver (in Python).

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ch4_reviewBtnTopRt").click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ch4_reviewBtnTopRt").click()
```

and got the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ch4_reviewBtnTopRt` to find the element? That doesn't appear anywhere in the sample html you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ch4_btnOrange").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below css selector

```
 input.ch4_btn.ch4_btnOrange.ch4_btnDropShadow.ch4_btnPlaceOrder
```

you can also try below xpath

```
 //input[@value='PLACE ORDER']
```